# An extra worksheet present when creating multiple sheets using phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, spreadsheet

I am creating an excel file with different sheets. The different sheets are created by iteration. But my iteration results in an extra sheet named worksheet. My code is:

```
        $result = fetch results from database;
        $count = COUNT($result);
        foreach ( $result as $key=>$value){ 
            $objPHPExcel->createSheet($key);   
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->setTitle($value['title']);  
        }
```

My database has got 3 results and it generates three worksheets along with a fourth one which is named as 'Worksheet'.

If I am using a checking condition with

```
if ($key > 0) {
     execute above code
}
else {
     $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setTitle($value['title']);
}
```

it works fine. why is it so? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. When you instantiate a new PHPExcel object using `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel()`, it is created with a single sheet called "worksheet"; delete that if you want to create only your own sheets

```
$objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the worksheet. But why it is working with that if condition?

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Baker's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902908/8958173) as always helped me but I want to expand and explain further on it.

I found that both `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel()` and `$objPHPExcel->createSheet()` create a single sheet called "worksheet". So use either one.

In the following sample which creates multiple sheets:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// First sheet
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(); // NOT NEEDED
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
// code for putting first sheet data

// Second sheet
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
// code for putting second sheet data

// Third, fourth sheets etc
```

`createSheet()` isn't needed for the first sheet where I've commented and it'll create that extra blank sheet. `new PHPExcel()` already made my first one me as he said.

So putting `$objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0)` at the end to remove it will work -- But just removing this unneeded line solves it the 'right' way and removes that redundancy. It seems like your code roughly does it like this.